# Requests - How to upload large chunks of file in requests?

Tags: file-upload, python-requests, upload, streaming

I have to upload large files (~5GB). I am dividing the file in small chunks (10MB), can't send all data(+5GB) at once(as the api I am requesting fails for large data than 5GB if sent in one request). The api I am uploading to,  has a specification that it needs minimum of 10MB data to be sent. I did use read(10485760) and send it via requests which works fine.

However, I do not want to read all the 10MB in the memory and if I leverage multithreading in my script, so each thread reading 10MB would cost me too much memory.

Is there a way I can send a total of 10MB to the api requests but read only 4096/8192 bytes at a time and transfer till I reach 10MB, so that I do not overuse memory.

Pls.note I cannot send the fileobj in the requests as that will use less memory but I will not be able to break the chunk at 10MB and entire 5GB data will go to the request, which I do not want.

Is there any way via requests. I see the httplib has it. https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/3.9/Lib/http/client.py - I will call the send(fh.read(4096) function here in loop till I complete 10MB and will complete one request of 10MB without heavy memory usage.

Answer (score 0):

this is what documentation says:
`In the event you are posting a very large file as a multipart/form-data request, you may want to stream the request. By default, requests does not support this, but there is a separate package which does - requests-toolbelt. You should read the toolbelt’s documentation for more details about how to use it.`

so try to `stream` the upload if it doesn't work as per your needs then go for `requests-toolbelt`

In order to `stream` the upload, you need to pass `stream=True` in the function call whether its `post` or `put`.

Comment: What is meant by "try to stream" the upload ? How to do that..Passing fileobj, does not help in reading only selected bytes and then upload. It will read the entire file. Also, I do not have a form so not sure about the "multipart/form-data", it's just I want to divide file in multiple parts and upload.